# Routing conditional with spring cloud streams functional

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, event-driven, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have some issues after the old imperative programming type was deprecated.
I have two microservices (one as publisher and the other as subscriber) and in the old way, with the annotation `@StreamListener(target = "events", condition = "headers['type']=='consumerPermissionEvent'")` i was able to have two functions listening only that records and now i don't know how to do it.

I was reading all the documentation [event routing](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/31/spring-cloud-stream-event-routing) and trying with the routing-expression but the two consumers are reading all the records.

The application yaml of the first microservies:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output: 
          destination: topicEvents
```

The seconds application yaml is:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      routing-expression: headers['type']
      definition: consumerPermissionEvent;consumerApiEvent
    stream:
      bindings:
        consumerPermissionEvent-in-0:
          destination: topicUsers
        consumerApiEvent-in-0:
          destination: topicUsers
```

I'm sending from the first microservice like that:

```java
@Autowired
private StreamBridge bridge;

public void send(PermissionEvent event){
    Message<PermissionEvent> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(event)
            .setHeader("type","consumerPermissionEvent").build();
    bridge.send("output", message);
}
```

And the second microservice has two consumers:

```java
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<ApiEvent>> consumerApiEvent() {
        return e -> log.debug("READED API EVENT: {}", e.getPayload());
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<PermissionEvent>> consumerPermissionEvent() {
        return e -> log.debug("READED PERMISSION EVENT: {}", e.getPayload());
    }
```

And the output logs from the second microservice:

```
[KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='topicUsers', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1] [20b662594644cf2e] DEBUG c.m.o.v.eda.subscribers.NotificationSuscriber - READED API EVENT: ApiEvent(apiId=null)
[KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='topicUsers', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1] [20b662594644cf2e] DEBUG c.m.o.v.eda.subscribers.NotificationSuscriber - READED PERMISSION EVENT: PermissionEvent(userRole=roleUseradsf)
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to enable routing first by using following property:

```
--spring.cloud.stream.function.routing.enabled=true
```

for more details, refer to https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function